# Accessing datasource of uipickerview load from uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uipickerview

I am trying to get datasource and selectRow for UIPickerview, which is being loaded using UIWebview. Although I have the reference of this object, anytime I set a delegate, the text disappears from the menu. Could anyone guide me as of how can I get the selection of the index for such referenced uipickerview from webview?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "UIPickerview which is being loaded using UIWebView"? Also, what is the menu you mention? It would be helpful if you would post some code.

Comment: Well lets assume there is a list element on a website that you select, iOS shows a pickerview for it. I think internally there is another class uiwebkitpicker, something like that which is being subclassed. Anyways, the problem is that, I need to capture the datasource of that pickerview, would it be possible to do it through some hack or use some sort of dom parser.